# Problems with Selecting a Gallery Image in OnActivityResult method

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin, onactivityresult

I got 2 problems in `OnActivityResult` method while trying to upload image accoding to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/selecting_a_gallery_image/). How can I solve them?[image]
The full code of the class is:

```
public class AddNewTourActivity : Activity
    {
        GettingCountry gettingCountry = new GettingCountry();
        private static int idOfChosenCountry, IdOfChosenCategory;
        private static string status, promptMessage;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AddNewTour);

            //clearing lists
            GettingCountry.listOfCountriesRoot.Clear();
            GettingCountry.countriesList.Clear();

            GettingCategories gc = new GettingCategories();
            //Getting list of countries
            gettingCountry.Fetch();

            //clearing listCategoriesRoot 
            GettingCategories.categoriesList.Clear();
            //getting categories method
            gc.GetCategories();
            Spinner categories_spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.categories_spinner);
            Spinner countries = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.countries);
            //adapter
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, GettingCategories.categoriesList);
            ArrayAdapter adapterCountries = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, GettingCountry.countriesList);
            categories_spinner.Adapter = adapter;
            countries.Adapter = adapterCountries;
            countries.ItemSelected += Countries_ItemSelected;
            categories_spinner.ItemSelected += Categories_spinner_ItemSelected;
            //FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.owner_id).Text = Login.user_id.ToString();

            var title = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.title);
            var image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.myImageView);
            var location = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.location);
            var description = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.description);
            var price = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.price);
            var min_capacity = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.min_capacity);
            var max_capacity = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.max_capacity);
            var duration = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.duration);
            var meet_place_address = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.meet_place_address);
            var meet_place_city = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.meet_place_city);
            var lat = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.lat);
            var lng = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.lng);

            //uploading image
            image.Click += Image_Click;
            //uploading image ENDED

            FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.add_tour_button).Click += delegate
            {
                //setting prompt message empty
                promptMessage = "";
                var client = new RestClient("http://api.locopal.com");
                var request = new RestRequest("/experience", Method.POST);

                //CHECKING THE CORRECTNESS OF THE USER'S INTRODUCTION TO ALL FIELDS
                if (title.Text.Length < 3)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Title must have at least 3 symbols.\n";
                }
                if (location.Text.Length < 3)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Location must have at least 3 symbols.\n";
                }
                if (description.Text.Length < 30)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Description length must be at least 30 symbols.\n";
                }

                //checking if price, capacity, etc... are integer values
                int res;
                bool priceIsInt = false;
                priceIsInt = Int32.TryParse(price.Text, out res);

                if (priceIsInt == false)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Price must be an integer value.\n";
                }

                bool minCapacityIsInt = false;
                minCapacityIsInt = Int32.TryParse(min_capacity.Text, out res);
                if (minCapacityIsInt == false)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Minimum capacity must be an integer value.\n";
                }

                bool maxCapacityIsInt = false;
                maxCapacityIsInt = Int32.TryParse(max_capacity.Text, out res);
                if (maxCapacityIsInt == false)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Maximum capacity must be an integer value.\n";
                }

                bool durationIsInt = false;
                durationIsInt = Int32.TryParse(duration.Text, out res);
                if (durationIsInt == false)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Duration must be an integer value.\n";
                }
                //checking if price, capacity, etc... are integer values ENDED

                if (meet_place_address.Text.Length < 3)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Address of meeting place must have at least 3 symbols.\n";
                }

                if (meet_place_city.Text.Length < 3)
                {
                    promptMessage += " City of meeting place must have at least 3 symbols.\n";
                }

                //checking if lat and lng are doubles
                double resDouble;

                bool latIsDouble = false;
                latIsDouble = Double.TryParse(lat.Text, out resDouble);
                if (latIsDouble == false)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Latitude must be a fractional value.\n";
                }

                bool lngIsDouble = false;
                lngIsDouble = Double.TryParse(lng.Text, out resDouble);
                if (lngIsDouble == false)
                {
                    promptMessage += " Longitude must be a fractional value.";
                }
                //checking if lat and lng are doubles ENDED

                //CHECKING THE CORRECTNESS OF THE USER'S INTRODUCTION TO ALL FIELDS ENDED

                request.AddParameter("api_token", Login.token);
                request.AddParameter("title", title.Text);
                request.AddParameter("location", location.Text);
                request.AddParameter("description", description.Text);
                request.AddParameter("price", price.Text);
                request.AddParameter("owner_id", Login.user_id);
                request.AddParameter("min_capacity", min_capacity.Text);
                request.AddParameter("max_capacity", max_capacity.Text);
                request.AddParameter("duration", duration.Text);
                request.AddParameter("duration_type", 1);
                request.AddParameter("meet_place_address", meet_place_address.Text);
                request.AddParameter("meet_place_city", meet_place_city.Text);
                request.AddParameter("meet_place_country", idOfChosenCountry);
                request.AddParameter("category_list[0]", IdOfChosenCategory);
                request.AddParameter("lat", lat.Text);
                request.AddParameter("lng", lng.Text);

                try
                {
                    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                    var content = response.Content;
                    var myContent = JObject.Parse(content);
                    status = myContent["status"].ToString();
                }
                catch { }

                if (status == "success")
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Tour added successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    //setting status variable to null to prevent issues with adding new places in future
                    status = null;
                    StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, promptMessage, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            };
        }

        private void Image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var imageIntent = new Intent();
            imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
            imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(
                Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);
        }

        private void Categories_spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            IdOfChosenCategory = e.Position;
        }

        private void Countries_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            idOfChosenCountry = gettingCountry.retrievingChoosenCountryId(GettingCountry.countriesList[e.Position].ToString());
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {

                var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.myImageView);
                imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the namespace from `RecyclerViewSample` to `RecyclerViewSampl`. I deleted only one letter. Then I added full path `RecyclerViewSample.Resource.Id.min_capacity` as an example to all elements of previous namespace. 
For example:
`SetContentView(RecyclerViewSample.Resource.Layout.AddNewTour);`
In another classes I did analogical references to this new namespace.
Such as:
`StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(RecyclerViewSampl.AddNewTourActivity)));`